# How to handle connection pools errors from spring-boot to mysql database?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, hikaricp

I'm working on a spring-boot application which connects to a CloudSQL (GCP managed mysql instance).

Recently I have started experiencing some situations which I can't understand well. 
When sudden influx of users come on the application, the database CPU utilization peaks and it stops responding. Then after few minutes everything comes back to normal.

People from GCP told that sudden bursts of incoming connections are causing this and database faced a max number of incoming connections which was at 668 when the outage happened.

The spring-boot application runs in kubernetes and it scales automatically. Max pods(containers) it has been scaled up to now is 70 and hikari(spring-boot connection pooling tool) configuration maximum-pool-size is set at 30.

```
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=60000
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=10
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=30
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=600000
spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=1800000
```

And this is a portion of mysql configuration below.

```
max_allowed_packet  33554432
max_binlog_cache_size   18446744073709547520
max_binlog_size 104857600
max_binlog_stmt_cache_size  18446744073709547520
max_connect_errors  100
max_connections 4030
max_delayed_threads 20
max_digest_length   1024
max_error_count 64
max_execution_time  0
max_heap_table_size 16777216
max_insert_delayed_threads  20
max_join_size   18446744073709551615
max_length_for_sort_data    1024
max_points_in_geometry  65536
max_prepared_stmt_count 16382
max_relay_log_size  0
max_seeks_for_key   18446744073709551615
max_sort_length 1024
max_sp_recursion_depth  0
max_tmp_tables  32
max_user_connections    0
max_write_lock_count    18446744073709551615
```

I will really appreciate some help.

Comment: is the MySQL also scaled horizontally? How many instances of MySQL is used?

Comment: @MohamedSanaulla MySQL is not scaled that way. It's only one instance with 120g ram.

Comment: Additional information request. 
# cores, any SSD devices on MySQL Host server. 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
From SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.